# GitHub Organisation transfer from one company to another company with all repositories

Tags: github, github-actions

My company **ABC** is taken over by Company **PQR** and **ABC** has private GitHub Organisation '*Org1*' With lots of repositories in it. I want to move/copy/transfer/export organisation '*Org1*'to new company **PQR** 's private GitHub Organisation '*Org1*' with all repositories

Is this possible in GitHub?

Comment: Please if you don't understand the requirements don't direct something, you directed me to move repo from GitHub to ZenHub whereas I have asked need to move the whole GitHub organisation itself to another Company's GitHub not outside GitHub

Comment: You probably need to contact GitHub https://support.github.com/ and see if they can help migrate behind the scene or with your assistance. Don't expect any outsider can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing support team link but mis leading someone is not the good, my code was actually being shared to ZenHub because I followed the suggested